# Ansible Register check / assert

Tags: python, ansible

I have a task to write a script in Ansible in which I need to prevent incorrect input and I am stuck.
Example:

```
 vars:
   record_name: test
   record_zone: example.com
   record_data: 0.0.0.0
   record_type: A
```

It is necessary to stop playing if in the first variable you wrote full name with the zone and record (test.example.com)

I was thinking that it would be possible to check for the symbol "."
But I don’t understand how to put this request in assert.

Tried using set_fact and this variable element in error_when, only error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific example concerning the `record_name` variable, you could use the [`fail` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fail_module.html):

```
- fail:
    msg: "record_name must not contain '.'"
  when: '"." in record_name'
```

You could accomplish pretty much the same thing with [`assert`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/assert_module.html):

```
- assert:
    that: '"." not in record_name'
    fail_msg: "record_name must not contain '.'"
  when: '"." in record_name'
```